# How do i handle HOC from it's wrapped component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, high-order-component

I have a `HOC` to handling loading using `axios`,

here's a code of `withAxiosHOC`:

```
export default (url, WrapComponent) => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        data: null,
        isLoading:false,
        isFailed:false,
        isError:false,
        message:null,
      };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      this.callAPI()
    }
    
    async callAPI(){
      //show loading
      // handle API and pass to wrapped component
      // hide loading
    }

    render() {
      if (this.state.isLoading) {
        return (
          //show loading UI
        )
      } else if(this.state.isFailed){
        return(
          //show Failed UI
        )
      } else if(this.state.isError){
        return(
          //show Error UI
        )
      }

      return (
        <WrapComponent data={this.state.data} {...this.props} />
      )
    }
  }
}
```

and usually i'm used `HOC` like this, let say `Home.js`:

```
export default withAxiosHttp(
  'https://reactnative.dev/movies.json',
  class Home extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        data:props.data
      }
    }
  
    render() {
      return(
        <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:Color.black}}>
          <MyText>{JSON.stringify(this.state.data, null, 2)}</MyText>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }
)
```

but sometimes i need to call the URL depend on state of my wrapped component,

something like this `Suggestion.js`:

```
export default withAxiosHttp(
  'https://exampleAPIneedDynamicValue.com/suggestion?lat='+this.state.position.lat+'&long='+this.state.position.long,
  class Suggestion extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        data:props.data,
        position:{lat:null, long:null}
      }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      let tempPosition = this.state.position
      tempPosition.lat = MyLatitude
      tempPosition.long = MyLongitude
      this.setState({position:tempPosition})
    }
  
    render() {
      return(
        <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:Color.black}}>
          <MyText>{JSON.stringify(this.state.data, null, 2)}</MyText>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }
)
```

as you see in `Suggestion.js`, i need to call a URL depending on `lat` and `long` of `position state`,
and `lat long state` only available in `wrappedComponent` of `HOC`,

**My Question:**

1. How do i handle HOC to run when `lat long` state is available in wrappedComponent?
2. does my HOC can be used to `POST method` also?

> Please give me a suggestion/answer in `React Native` scope

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `url` parameter is a function instead of a string.

In `withAxiosHOC`

```
async callAPI(){
   axios.get(url(this.state)).then(data => {
       //logic here
   })
}
```

Your `Suggestion.js` will be

```
export default withAxiosHttp(
  (state) => {
      return 'https://exampleAPIneedDynamicValue.com/suggestion?lat='+state.position.lat+'&long='+state.position.long
  },
  class Suggestion extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        data:props.data,
        position:{lat:null, long:null}
      }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      let tempPosition = this.state.position
      tempPosition.lat = MyLatitude
      tempPosition.long = MyLongitude
      this.setState({position:tempPosition})
    }
  
    render() {
      return(
        <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:Color.black}}>
          <MyText>{JSON.stringify(this.state.data, null, 2)}</MyText>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: `(state)=>{return....}` `state` in `Suggestion.js` of `HOC` url param is `state` from `withAxiosHOC` i've tried to `console.log(state)` before `return [myurl]`